# Google App Engine deferred.defer() failing when method returns

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception, task

I'm trying to use google.appengine.ext.deferred to run a Task.  I am passing a method to the defer() method, and that method runs successfully, but upon returning, a ValueError is thrown:

```
  File ".../admin.py", line 73, in post
    result = deferred.defer(meeple_tasks.buildGames())
      File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 198, in _curry_callable
        raise ValueError("obj must be callable")
    ValueError: obj must be callable
```

Here is where I call defer:

```
result = deferred.defer(meeple_tasks.buildGames())
```

buildGames() will return True when completed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use:

```
result = deferred.defer(meeple_tasks.buildGames)
```

If you use `buildGames()`, that invokes the function *right then and there*, passing the *return value* to `defer()`. By removing the parenthesis, you pass the function itself to defer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your deferred task like this:

`deferred.defer(meeple_tasks.buildGames)`

"obj must be callable" means that (in your case) the value True is not callable.  How I wrote the deferred call with "defer" the buildGames method call to another process (or task) by inserting it in a queue and letting the AppEngine framework deal with it.

Note that you cannot return anything with deferred tasks.  They will be running on a different process and probably on a totally different server.  As per the documentation they are Background workers.